# DBeaver results show datetime but CSV export displays time only

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, dbeaver

When I run a query using an Oracle DB in DBeaver the results show in datetime format. [DBeaver Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FuBA.png)

Recently, however, once the exports are exported to csv, I open the csv and only the time mm:ss are displayed. [CSV Result Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQf6N.png)

I have to format back to the full datetime on every column once opening the csv.

Is there something I am missing in the DBeaver export settings?  I am not sure why this started happening. [DBeaver Export Format Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfblP.png)

The data format settings seem to be correct as well. [DBeaver Data Format Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2T8P.png)